# Error: message: "Unauthenticated." in laravel and vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8

I'm using laravel and vue and I'm trying to get my middleware to work.

What is happening is when I login to my app as a customer and I check my Network tab in my dev tools, my routes that I'm protecting is saying

```
message: "Unauthenticated."
```

Here is my middleware

```
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'customer')
        {
            return $next($request);
        }else{
            abort(403);
        }
    }
```

And this is my api routes

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'isCustomer'])->group(function(){
    Route::get('/customer/getItems/{customer}', [ CustomerController::class, 'getItems']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're mentioning the middleware `RedirectIfAuthenticated` then can you try this

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'customer')
        {
            return redirect ('/home');
        }else{
            abort(403);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know if I should have mentioned this, but I have 2 middlewares that check if the user is a customer or an admin. I did try what you suggested, but I wasn't even able to access my login page

Comment: Hi, if you use 2 middlewares to separate the routes, I suggest you edit your route with the middleware you want to allow access to customer for example. The route you currently use is the default auth based on the config file.

Comment: My routes would look like I have above in my question. The only difference is that for customers I have `isCustomer` and for admins I have `isAdmin`

Comment: Your middleware that checks. Why are you not putting it into your route? Currently, you are using this 'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
you can find this from the App\Http\Kernel php file. The middlewares that you created - you also need to register it on this file.